# Magento 2 : Getting Interface Error on Frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, error, frontend, interface

I'm getting following error on frontend.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\App\RequestSafetyInterface in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(126): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'requestSafety', 'Magento\\Configu...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Configu...', Array, Array) #4 C: in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73
```

How to fix this error?

I have installed fresh magento v2.1.3 and enabled couple of my modules and got this error. So I disabled those modules but error persists, what is root cause of this error and how to fix it? 
[image]

Comment: I got the same error due to missing files in vendor.

Comment: Did you fixed it?

Comment: Yes by reinstalling everything as i tried multiple thing